# The meaning of ''give up''

Tags: meaning, idioms, meaning-in-context, ambiguity

*If Molière **had given himself up to his abyss**, Pascal — with his — would look like a journalist.*

E. M. Cioran, *All Gall is Divided*

What does ''give up'' means here? Does it mean that Molière decided to look upon his abyss, like take his abyss into consideration? Could someone ''translate'' this for me in a less equivocal manner?

Comment: It almost certainly means "surrender", but without more context I can't be sure.

Comment: This is the whole aphorism, sorry, there are no further details I can give as I virtually have no context.

Comment: Indeed, "surrender" it is. Or "devote", with a similar sense of relinquishing one's freedom.

Comment: @RJH you should make that an answer.

Comment: @Skooba – done, but with some guilt at the simplicity of it.

Comment: @RJH my opinion is for some users of this SE site that are ESL find some of these "simple" answer very helpful. Not saying that would make a difference as you have answered the question. The question was not "difficult" so why should the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It [means](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/give--up?s=t) to "surrender" or to "devote" (or perhaps a combination), either one with a similar sense of relinquishing one's freedom.

*If Molière had surrendered/devoted himself to his abyss, Pascal — with his — would look like a journalist.*